# AdMobで本番のバナー広告が表示されない。テスト広告は表示できた。

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml, unity2d, admob

多くの人が抱えている問題だと思います。

テスト広告の表示には成功しています。

---

UnityゲームにAdMob広告を表示させたいです。
形式はバナー、プラットフォームはAndroidです。

僕はこの問題を解決するためにStack Overflowで検索していると`「AdMobの支払い情報を記入すれば表示されるようになる」`と書いてありますが、8000円以上の収益がない限り、それらの設定をすることはできません。
AdMobコンソールの [お支払い] -> [設定を管理する] の設定はすべて完了しています。

また`「広告ユニットは作成してから表示されるまで時間がかかる」`という回答もありました。
しかし、広告ユニットを作ってからすでに２週間が経とうとしています。

これらの回答はこの問題を解決させることはできませんでした。

僕は質問サイトでよく`「AppIDとadUnitIDを書き間違えていませんか？」`という回答を見かけます。しかし、ほとんどの質問者が書き間違えをしていなくて、その質問が解決済みになっていません。

他に何か原因があるのでしょうか？どなたか回答お願いします。

---

#### 広告を表示させるためのスクリプト

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    public void Start()
    {
         this.RequestBanner();
    }

    private void RequestBanner()
    {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "My UnitID";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "My Ad Unit ID";
    #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

        bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

adUnitIDの値をテストIDにすると広告は表示されます。
テストIDは以下のものです。

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

しかし、自分で作ったユニットIDでは表示されませんでした。

---

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged
with your application's manifest, adding the necessary
activity and permissions required for displaying ads.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity.ads"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application>
            <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXXX -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="My APP ID"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

個人的な意見ですが、このスクリプトとXMLファイルはこの問題に関係ないと思います。というのもテスト広告は無事表示できているわけですから...

---

#### ログ

Starting auto-resolution before scene build...

> Starting auto-resolution before scene build...
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
>   GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
>   GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:OnPostProcessScene()
>   UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces:OnSceneProcess(Scene, BuildReport)

Dummy .ctor

> Dummy .ctor
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:.ctor() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:28)
>   GoogleMobileAds.GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory:BuildBannerClient() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Platforms/GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory.cs:27)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
>   GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:.ctor(String, AdSize, AdPosition) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/BannerView.cs:34)
>   AdMob:RequestBanner() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:26)
>   AdMob:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:12)

Dummy CreateBannerView

> Dummy CreateBannerView
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:CreateBannerView(String, AdSize, AdPosition) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:90)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:.ctor(String, AdSize, AdPosition) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/BannerView.cs:35)
>   AdMob:RequestBanner() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:26)
>   AdMob:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:12)

Dummy LoadAd

> Dummy LoadAd
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:LoadAd(AdRequest) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:100)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:LoadAd(AdRequest) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/BannerView.cs:68)
>   AdMob:RequestBanner() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:32)
>   AdMob:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:12)

Dummy ShowBannerView

> Dummy ShowBannerView
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:ShowBannerView() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:105)
>   GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView:Show() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/BannerView.cs:80)
>   AdMob:RequestBanner() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:34)
>   AdMob:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/AdMob.cs:12)

Dummy Dummy Dummyといっぱい言われてますがこれは普通の事らしいです。
AdMobコンソール自体に問題があると思われるためログには不具合やおかしなところは見つからないはず・・・

---

#### 参考にさせていただいたブログ・サイト

- [Google AdMob Unity Get Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start)
- [[Unity] AdMob 広告をAndroidに実装する](https://uni.gas.mixh.jp/unity/android-admob.html)
- [Unityで作ったゲームにAdMob広告を実装する方法【バナー広告編】](https://freesworder.net/unity-admob-banner/)
- [【Unity】AdMobをUnityアプリに実装する方法](https://www.clrmemory.com/unity/apps-admob-ads/)
- [【Unity】AdMob組み込み方法](http://www.kurisankaku.xyz/entry/2017/03/19/192245)

---

#### SDKマネージャーについての情報

(これらの情報はおそらく必要ないと思いますが)

- SDK platforms → Android 8.1, Android 7.1.1, Android 6.0
- Google Play Services → インストール済み (version 49)
- CMake → インストール済み
- NDK → インストール済み
- Support Repository → すべてインストール済み

Comment: 重複候補: [UnityでAdMobを表示させるためのPlayer Settingsの設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50102/unity%e3%81%a7admob%e3%82%92%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%aeplayer-settings%e3%81%ae%e8%a8%ad%e5%ae%9a)

Comment: 前回の質問を詳しく書いただけのように見えるのですが。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50102/

Comment: 参考: [AdMobヘルプ - 広告が表示されない場合のトラブルシューティング](https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685?hl=ja)

Comment: 「以前に AdMob を使ってアプリに広告表示ができましたか？」 -> いいえ   
「最近（24時間以内）広告ユニット ID を作成しましたか？」 -> いいえ   
「エラー ログがありましたか？」 -> いいえ   
「どのフォーマットを実装しようとしていますか？」 -> バナー   　

テスト広告は問題なく表示され、サイズの変更をせずにユニットIDを変えました。サイズの描写ミスでは無いと思います。